# How to get the metadata of saved object/file in aws s3 using amplify - flutter

Tags: flutter, amazon-s3, metadata, aws-amplify

I am new to AWS amplify framework. I am saving images from my flutter app with custom metadata. In the same way, I would like to use those metadata to display in my app along with the saved image in the detailed view.

But the issue is, that I can retrieve the key alone from the `StorageItem` class. How could I get the metadata of the saved object from the s3 bucket using flutter?

Thanks.

Comment: Does not seem to be included, 
* https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/597
* https://github.com/aws-amplify/docs/issues/3266